# Classical Piano Piece, could you help me to identify it?

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

could you help me to identify this  piece?  Here it is  , on 17:22,  on this  Youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vWvHaaMJnM&t=1091s  I am not very knowledgeable about music. Thanks a lot, oscar ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The piece playing from 17:26 to 19:27 in Chopin's [Prelude in D Minor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHcEH2Rliko), op. 28 no. 4.

The entire video incorporates [Chopin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric_Chopin)'s music.

4:30 - 6:45: [Prelude in A Flat Major](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyiUXrMlDWo), op. 28 no. 17
6:51 - 7:40: [Prelude in C Major](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpEit_Lll0k), op. 28 no. 1
8:42 - 10:30: [Prelude in G Major](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cf8o9gsRvBo), op. 28 no. 2
12:10 - 13:10: [Prelude in C Sharp Minor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viMrBOGIpbI), op. 28 no. 10
14:15 - 15:25: [Prelude in B Major](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBw0LCSkKPU), op. 28 no. 21
15:40 - 17:24: [Prelude in F major](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdHZGBfr64w), op. 28 no. 23
17:26 - 19:27: [Prelude in D Minor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHcEH2Rliko), op. 28 no. 4
19:45 - 21:45 [Prelude in B Flat Major](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1Y-KEXoaxA), op. 28 no. 11
21:48 - 22:25 [Prelude in F Minor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1Y-KEXoaxA), op. 28 no. 18
22:29 - 25:38 [Prelude in F Sharp Major](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYLy-5lPI6w), op. 28 no. 13

Comment: INDEED!  It's "The Storm" Chopin's Prelude...Marvellous  Piece!! Thanks a lot, Aaron!!!    All the Best  nice friend, oscar;

Comment: Thanks, Oscar. Much appreciated if you would mark the answer as "accepted". (By clicking the check-mark next to the answer.) All best.

Comment: Done; you there?